# Google Contacts Tasks Calendar API Cost

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api, google-tasks

I know the Google Maps API charges sites that use the Maps API heavily.

I can't find similar information on charges for Tasks, Calendars, and Contacts. Are there such limits or are these totally free? Can anyone point me to a place this is explicitly stated?

Comment: Google it?  :)  I've got nothing for you except a smart @ss answer...

Answer (score 7):

Those are APIs associated with Google Apps. 
There are no costs for these APIs.

To confirm this, go to your API Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/) then click on Services.
If the service (API) has a "Pricing" link, then it does have it's own pricing schema. If not you are limited to the Courtesy limit indicated.

Hope this helps. Good luck.